# How to open D3.js Context Menu with right click

Tags: javascript, d3.js, contextmenu

I draw the line on the screen by the user with d3.js. What I want to do is open the context menu with a right-click when the process is finished. This menu must be 'done' and 'undo'. How can I do it?

```js
let line;

let vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1280)
  .attr("height", 610)
  .on("click", mousedown)
  .on("contextmenu", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
  let m = d3.mouse(this);
  line = vis.append("line")
    .attr("x1", m[0])
    .attr("y1", m[1])
    .attr("x2", m[0])
    .attr("y2", m[1]);

  vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
  let m = d3.mouse(this);
  line.attr("x2", m[0])
    .attr("y2", m[1]);
}

function mouseup() {
  vis.on("mousemove", null);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[this post](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/) may help you.

full detailed step by step guide to build a context menu with javascript and css.

you only need to link context items with d3.js operations for your actions